# Authorize.net curl error returning when trying to post payments after moving to new server

Tags: php, ssl, curl, authorize.net

I am getting a PHP curl error when posting payments after moving our PHP code from a linux server to a new windows server.  The error is below:

```
error #60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.
```

To try and fix the situation I commented out the below line but still get the same error:

```
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/ssl/cert.pem');
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't transfer over the cacert files (or they are not in the right location) that your CURL wants. You cannot omit them if you want to hit a SSL url.

Comment: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/SSL-Certificate-Problem-Another-Authorize-net-Outage/td-p/62246

Comment: If it was in a wrong location wouldn't I get a CURL 77 error?

Comment: Nope... its a SSL issue when it tries to connect. You will actually see this error on all your CURL actions to https urls :( You need your local cacert file setup (php doesn't come with it anymore). Either its setup globally, or you set it per curl action (like you show you had before). I tend to put it globally so all my curl use the same pem file.

Comment: Look through that link John posted. Useful details there. You'll get it sorted out, don't worry.

Comment: If I set it in the php.ini folder can delete it where I set it in PHP?